# onLocationChanged not getting called - Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, geolocation, location, xamarin.android

Below is a Service class which fetches the location. But the onLocationChanged call bask method is not getting called. Followed the documentation found [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/location/). My service is getting started no problems in that, but the call backs method are not getting called neither are there any exceptions. Can someone look at the code and tell me if I am missing something. Thanks.

```
[Service]
    public class LocationService : Service, ILocationListener
    {
        public static LocationManager locMgr;

        [Obsolete ("deprecated")]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId){

            Console.WriteLine ("LocationService-OnStartCommand");
            locMgr = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
            Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
            {
                Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
            };
            IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = locMgr.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);
            string Provider;
            if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
            {
                Provider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
                Console.WriteLine ("LocationService-acceptableLocationProviders.Any()");
            }
            else
            {
                Provider = String.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine ("LocationService-String.Empty");
            }

            if(locMgr.IsProviderEnabled(Provider))
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("LocationService-Provider enabled: "+Provider);
                locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (Provider, 0, 0, this);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Provider is not available. Does the device have location services enabled?");
            }

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged (Location location)
        {
            Toast.MakeText (Application.Context, "location changed", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            Console.WriteLine ("LocationService-OnLocationChanged");
            Console.WriteLine (""+location.Latitude);
        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled (string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled (string provider)
        {
        }

        public void OnStatusChanged (string provider, Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }

        #region implemented abstract members of Service
        public override IBinder OnBind (Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        #endregion

        public override void OnDestroy ()
        {
            base.OnDestroy ();
            Console.WriteLine ("LocationService-OnDestroy");
            locMgr.RemoveUpdates (this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here : `locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates (Provider, 0, 0, this);`

Put other thing than 0 in both second and third parameters (respectivly minimum interval and minimum distance between update).

Comment: I have tried other values as well. Before it was 2000, 1 respectively but still dint work

Comment: Can you put the logcat of all the Console.WriteLine ?

Comment: I use _locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(locationProvider,5, 1, this);

5 = Meters